# codeigniter : How to load two third party libraries using composer - $config[composer_autoload]

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php

I am using two third party libraries in codeigniter

(1) php spreadsheet
(2) mpdf

libraries are installed by composer, 
path of spreadsheet

(project folder/vendor/...........)

path of mpdf

(project folder/vendorone/......)

if i set $config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';  then spreadsheet library working

& if i set $config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendorone/autoload.php';  then mpdf library working

but i wants to load both of these library as below e.g

$config['composer_autoload'] =array('vender1/autoload.php','vendor/autoload.php');

how is it possible?

Comment: whats wrong in that question,?

Answer (score 1):

**I assume that you installed composer correctly (on Windows) and added it to your environment's PATH variable.**

You need to follow the steps below:

1. Go to `application` directory
2. Create a `composer.json` file inside the `application` directory.
3. Add required packages to `composer.json` file. i.e.

```
{
    "require": {
        "mpdf/mpdf": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*"
    }
}
```

4. Save and Close `composer.json` file.
5. Open `Command Prompt` and point to `application` directory.
6. Run `composer install` or `php composer.phar install` which works for you. If the PATH variable is set correctly, the `composer install` command should work.
7. If the command runs successfully, the packages will be installed at `application/vendor` directory.
8. Check if there is a `autoload.php` file inside the vendor directory.
9. Change `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` in `application/config/config.php` file.
10. Use installed libraries as per their documentation.

I hope it should work for you.

Comment: i dont have any probelm with installation, my question is i have two third party libraries, 1 is spread sheet ad another one is mpdf
i downloaded both using composer, 
and $config['composer_autoload'] =sprdshet path;
path is provide and after everything is wokring fine, but now i wants to use mpdf too, but 

if i use $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;  or $config['composer_autoload'] = path of vendor; then i can run only one library at a time.

Comment: Have you tried above steps? Maybe not. You have installed 2 library separately but composer.json isn't updated.

Comment: what if i have same steps for both libraries? i cant paste both lib files in one folder (application/vendor).

Comment: If you need to use both library using composer autoloader, you must need to have both library insatalled under same Composer package auto-loader script `autoload.php` which is automatically created by composer when you run `install` command. Because you can pass only one string in the `$config['composer_autoload']` config var. By default it does not support an array. If you would like to supply an array of composer package auto-loader script, maybe you need to customize CI core codes which I don't suggest.

Comment: As an easy solution, include both library in the same auto-loader script either use `spl_autoload_register` for them. I am not so much experienced but trying to answer to learn the best practices. Please let me know also if you find a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy all the folders from *vendorone* folder to the vendor folder

Comment: two libraries are different, am i need to paste?